# Angularjs: Validating directive components with or without forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very simple modal which contains a text area and a button. I have created a directive for the text area as follows:

```
app.directive('vipTextArea', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/common/textArea-partial.html',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            textAreaLabel: '@',
            textAreaName: '@',
            textRequired: '@',
            iconLabel: '@',
            textAreaIcon: '@',
            formName: '@',
            value : '=ngModel'
        }
    }

});
```

And here is the template:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 noPadding">
  <label>{{ textAreaLabel }}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 noPadding rightAlign">
     <vip-button-icon button-title="{{ iconLabel }}" icon-class="{{ textAreaIcon }}"></vip-  button-icon>
</div>
<br/>
<textarea name="{{ textAreaName }}" ng-model="value" class="textAreaSize" ng-required=" {{    textRequired }}" ng-class="{ inputError: ({{ formName }}.{{ textAreaName }}.$error.required && {{ formName }}.{{ textAreaName }}.$dirty) }"></textarea>
<p class="errorMsg" ng-show="{{ formName }}.{{ textAreaName }}.$error.required && {{ formName }}.{{ textAreaName }}.$dirty">This field is required</p>
```

I am using this directive here:

```
<form name="viewCertificate">
<modal-header modal-title="View Certificate"></modal-header>
<div class="modal-body modalBodyHeight">
    <vip-text-area form-name="viewCertificate" text-area-name="certificate" text-area-label="Certificate text below" text-required="true" icon-label="Upload" text-area-icon="upload" ng-model="certificate"></vip-text-area>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <vip-button form-name="viewCertificate" button-title="Ok" button-size="small" button-color="blue" ng-click="ok()"></vip-button>
    <vip-button form-name="viewCertificate" button-title="Cancel" button-size="small" button-color="white" ng-click="cancel()" class="buttonMargin"></vip-button>
</div></form>
```

All I am trying to achieve is validate the text area if it is empty. I am a newbie to angular, so please correct me if I am using this incorrectly. I am planning on using other directives like custom input fields, so need a common solution for all possible components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your form to your directive scope like this:

```
.directive('vipTextArea', function() {
     return {
      require: ['^form','ngModel'],
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/common/textArea-partial.html',
      scope: {
        textAreaLabel: '@',
        textAreaName: '@',
        textRequired: '@',
        iconLabel: '@',
        textAreaIcon: '@',
        formName: '@',
        value : '=ngModel'
     },
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
      scope.form = ctrl[0];
     }
 }
```

and then update your paragraph with the scope form:

```
    <p ng-show="form.{{ textAreaName }}.$invalid && form.{{ textAreaName }}.$dirty">This field is required</p>
```